# Excel cell wise substraction

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I have a worksheet in excel where i need to perform subtraction only either of the column contains value and result should be stored in a cell automatically for each cell. for eg
**strong text**

**JobExpense    Advance   Balance

4500             100       4400

8000             4000      4000

9800              5000     4800**

consider this as my sheet I need to store the contents of Balance columns automatically when  user enters value in Advance columns.
any help is appreciable. formula,vbscipt whatever.
I have tried formula,but it will always show zeros whenever formulas are used in the columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

---

The below code is provided assuming that the Job Expense is ColumnA,Advance in columnB and Balance in ColumnC.

The below code will work when any change occurs in ColumnB cells.

---

---

Copy the below code and do right click on sheet tab and select view code and paste it.

Close the VBA window (Alt+Q to close VBA window) and return to that sheet and check.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Column = 2 Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        With Target
            .Offset(, 1).Value = Val(.Offset(, -1).Value) - Val(.Value)
        End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have tried a lot functions but this is best. Thanks buddy